# JavaScript: Why is it so with windows.parent?

Tags: javascript

Why is it so that when you use `window.parent.showMessage("Video Is OK");` inside a .js file you've included on a page, it won't work, but only if it's on the page itself..?

Can you fix this?

Comment: Please provide a better description of your problem.

Comment: I do not have a problem, please read again and you'll understand. I want know WHY window.parent doesnt work if it's inside a .js file included on index.php, like it works if its on index.php in <head> section of the file..

Comment: The grammar is a little confusing but I think what he is asking is this:  "Why does this work if I put it in a `<script>` tag in the page HTML, but not when I include it in a separate js file"?

Comment: @Azzyh it **does** work, so long as nothing else is wrong. Please describe exactly what evidence you have that it does not work - for example, a sample page that shows what you think to be a problem.

Comment: for your "in a .js file" page, make sure the page including that js file doesn't have a JS error which is causing the script to fail loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two scenarios that I can think of where you'd want to use [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent). The first is when you have a window open another window using `window.open`. The other is where the first window uses an `iframe` to load a page. In the former case, it appears as though you actually want to use [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener), as ukostin has said. In the latter case, `window.parent` works fine. Both methods work properly whether the code is inline or loaded from an external JS file. Here are some tests:

**POPUP**

parentWindow.htm:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>function showMsg(msg){alert(msg);}</script>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('childWindow.htm','child','width=300,height=100')">Open</a>
</body>
</html>
```

externalWindow.js:

```
function showMsgExternal(msg){window.opener.showMsg(msg);}
```

childWindow.htm:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>function showMsgInline(msg){window.opener.showMsg(msg);}</script>
    <script src="externalWindow.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="showMsgInline('inline')">Inline</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showMsgExternal('external')">External</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**IFRAME**

parentFrame.htm:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>function showMsg(msg){alert(msg);}</script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="childFrame.htm" width="300" height="100"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

externalFrame.js:

```
function showMsgExternal(msg){window.parent.showMsg(msg);}
```

childFrame.htm:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>function showMsgInline(msg){window.parent.showMsg(msg);}</script>
    <script src="externalFrame.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="showMsgInline('inline')">Inline</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="showMsgExternal('external')">External</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use window.opener as link to the parent window.